# Echo an array that is numbered

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, echo

I am trying to echo an array. I have 2 arrays. $phone1 and $phone2. I'm trying to echo them in a for loop.

```
for($i=0; $i<2; $i++){
echo '<td>'.$phone.$i.['name'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$phone.$i.['merk'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$phone.$i.['besturingssysteem'].'</td>';
}
```

Now the problem is I have no idea how I am going to do this. I have 2 arrays and I want to echo them both but not by giving the full array name like $phone1; This is because there are going to be many more of these arrays and it has to be automated. Please help.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Why you using 'dot' ($phone.$i.['name']) the way is $arr[index][index] ($phone[$i]['name'])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never use numerically named variables like `$phone1`, `$phone2` etc. Whenever you do that, what you really want is *one array* called `$phones`:

```
$phones = [
    ['name' => ..., 'merk' => ..., ...],
    ['name' => ..., 'merk' => ..., ...],
    ...
];
```

You then loop through it like this:

```
foreach ($phones as $phone) {
    echo $phone['name'];
    echo $phone['merk'];
    ...
}
```